# AngularJS no expression replacement with dynamic data in scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope, expression

first of all: AngularJS beginner over here so maybe this question is the simplest ever or I have just not enough knowledge yet (though I don't figure out what to google for ;) )

I have just started to use Angular.js and tried to compute the date difference between two dates in a controller.

Code:

```
angular.module('DateDiffer', []);

angular.module('DateDiffer').controller('CountdownCtrl', function($scope) {
    var dnow = Date.now();
    var dtgt = new Date(2015, 8, 14);
    var msecday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    var diff = Math.round(Math.abs((dtgt.getTime() - dnow.getTime())/msecday));

    $scope.days = diff;
});
```

and the simple html snippet looks like this:

```
<div class="jumbotron area area-dark" ng-controller="CountdownCtrl">
    <div class="container content slogan" id="countdown">
        Computed <strong id="days">{{days}}</strong> days!
    </div>
</div>
```

So far for the code.

But: the {{days}} expression won't get evaluated to the computed value from the controller. 
Funny: If I change the days-variable in the controller to something static - just works fine.

I think I'm missing a substancial thing here - anyone there who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of Date.now() is not valid in angular js

Use simple new Date() for current date.

```
app.controller('CountdownCtrl', function ($scope) {
   var dnow = new Date();
var dtgt = new Date(2015, 8, 14);
dtgt.setMonth(dtgt.getMonth() - 1);
var msecday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var diff = Math.round(Math.abs((dtgt.getTime() - dnow.getTime())/msecday));

$scope.days = diff;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dh46wvbz/1/)

**UPDATE:-**

Subtract one month as month starts from 0

Comment: Note: Javascript months start at 0 so you will have to -1 off of the month to get the correct amount days. The example show 204 days when in fact its 174.

Comment: Glad to help you out :-)